# Cauchy Schwartz Inequality Step In The Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

In one of the proofs we come to a quadratic formula namely

$$\|u\|^2-2\lambda|\alpha|^2+\lambda^2|a|^2\|v\|^2$$

Next we look at the discriminant $$0\leq 4|a|^4-4\|u\|^2|a|^2\|v\|^2$$

How do we know that the discriminant is $0\leq \text{discriminant}$  and not $0>\text{discriminant}$?

Where $a=\langle u,v \rangle$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Without further information, we can't know it. We need to know how $a$, $u$ and $v$ are related or defined.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt Sorry, added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that $$a.a \geq 0 \\\forall \lambda \to <u,\lambda v>.<u,\lambda v> \geq 0\\u.u+\lambda^2v.v  +2\lambda u.v \geq 0\\ (1)\Delta=0\\u=v \to<u,\lambda u>.<u,\lambda u>=0 \checkmark\\(2)\Delta <0 \\
(2 u.v)^2-4(u.u)(v.v)< 0\\4u.v < 4|u||u||v||v| $$can you go on  ?$(1) \cup (2) \to$ 
$$u.v \leq ||u||\times||v||$$

Comment: So the discriminant is non positive sa the coefficient of the polynomial is positive and greater or equal to $0$ (as the proof starts) so it has at most one sloution

Comment: @gbox :you are  right  , But I show a clue . can separate it to $$\Delta =0 
 , \Delta <0$$